# Is there a plugin to insert pre-defined link into editor?

Tags: plugins, editor

After searching several hours, I've decided to crowd-source this one.  I have a client who uses Wordpress very frequently, they often have to create a link to a certain page for collecting donations - the issue is they always get the link wrong (long story, but they always screw it up!).  I've been searching for a plugin or tutorial on how I can add a button to the editor that would automatically add the link to their post  - ensuring the link is always correct. As mentioned I searched several hours and was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a button to the Tinymce editor that adds a pre defined link like this youtube button:

[image]

Put this in your functions.php theme file:

```
// Hook into WordPress
add_action('init', 'mylink_button');

// Create Our Initialization Function
function mylink_button() {

   if ( ! current_user_can('edit_posts') && ! current_user_can('edit_pages') ) {
     return;
   }

   if ( get_user_option('rich_editing') == 'true' ) {
     add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', 'add_plugin' );
     add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'register_button' );
   }

}

// Register Our Button
function register_button( $buttons ) {
    array_push( $buttons, "|", "mylink" );
    return $buttons;
}

// Register Our TinyMCE Plugin
function add_plugin( $plugin_array ) {
    $plugin_array['mylink'] = get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ) . '/link.js';
    return $plugin_array;
}
```

And then make a link.js file and put it in your theme root with this in it:

```
// JavaScript Document
(function() {
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.mylink', {
        init : function(ed, url) {
            ed.addButton('mylink', {
                title : 'My Link',
                image : url+'/mylink.png',
                onclick : function() {
                     ed.selection.setContent('http://mylink.com');

                }
            });
        },
        createControl : function(n, cm) {
            return null;
        },
    });
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('mylink', tinymce.plugins.mylink);
})();
```

Change http://mylink.com to the link you want to add.
Also add a icon called mylink.png in the theme root.

Comment: Pontius - Excellent post and example code. This is exactly what I was searching for! Thank you! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `dbx_post_advanced` hook is for, but you might be able to use it to do what you want.

```
static function insert_some_text( $arg1 ) {
   global $post ;

   if( $post->post_name == '' ) {
       $post->post_content = 'Some Hello World' ;
   }
}
add_action('dbx_post_advanced', 'insert_some_text');
```

Add this code into your functions.php and modify it. The `post_name` check you may want to replace with checking the URL for `post-new.php`.

Comment: Misunderstood the post and this doesn't answer the question - which is to add a button to the editor. Or the original question didn't mention adding a button?